# Cannot Convert type System.DateTime to String

Tags: c#, datetime

I want to add 35 days to endA and store it in string AA and use that AA in my if statement to compare today's date and date in AA
But in the line `AA = Convert.ToDateTime(enddateA).AddDays(35);` I get an error saying  **Cannot Convert type System.DateTime to String** it works if I do it through `var A = Convert.ToDateTime(enddateA).AddDays(35);` but than i cannot use it out of the scope.

```
string enddateA = "";
string dateNowA = "";
string AA = "";

string UPDATE_COMPLETE = String.Format("SELECT [FINAL_END_DATE] FROM [Campus6_convert].[dbo].[ACADEMICCALENDAR] where ACADEMIC_YEAR = '" + year + "'  and ACADEMIC_TERM='" + academicterm + "'  and  ACADEMIC_SESSION='A'");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(UPDATE_COMPLETE, con);

myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{
    enddateA = (myReader["FINAL_END_DATE"].ToString());
    AA = Convert.ToDateTime(enddateA).AddDays(35);

    dateNowA = DateTime.Now.ToString();

    Console.WriteLine("" + AA + "");
}
myReader.Close();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Dispose();
con.Close();

if ( AA  == dateNowA)
{
    using (SqlConnection coe = new SqlConnection("server=fcpcdb02; database=campus6_convert; user id=""; password="";"))
    {
        coe.Open();

        string UPDATE_COMPLETEE = String.Format("UPDATE [Campus6_convert].[dbo].[TRANSCRIPTDETAIL] SET FINAL_GRADE = 'F', REVISION_OPID='WFLOW', REVISION_DATE='" + revisiondate + "', REVISION_TIME='" + currentDateString + "' where FINAL_GRADE='I' and ACADEMIC_YEAR = '" + year + "'  and ACADEMIC_TERM='" + academicterm + "'  and  ACADEMIC_SESSION='A'");
        SqlCommand cd = new SqlCommand(UPDATE_COMPLETEE, coe);
        cd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cd.Dispose();
        coe.Close();
    }    
}
```

Comment: What is the dataType of FINAL_END_DATE in the database?

Comment: `AA` is a string and you're saying `Convert.ToDateTime(enddateA).AddDays(35);` which returns a date of course. Either declare AA as a `DateTime` or call `.AddDays(35).ToString()`

Comment: And you have a SQL injection in your code. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You miss the command `ToString()` to your `addDays(35)`:

```
AA = Convert.ToDateTime(enddateA).AddDays(35).ToString()
```

BTW: What is the type of `FINAL_END_DATE`?

Comment: This is true, but lacks a bit of explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Your AA variable is declared as "string", the command "Convert.ToDateTime(enddateA).AddDays(35)" will return a "DateTime" instance, that's why you cannot assign it to the AA variable

You can declare another "DateTime" variable, like you did with "var A = (...)" or you can convert it back to string with "Convert.ToDateTime(enddateA).AddDays(35)"

Comment: Great! Just adding information in case you wanted to use DateTime Methods :D